# how can I use new thread in android widget

Tags: widget, handler

```
 @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager 
 appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds, null);


} 

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds, final Intent receiveIntent) {

     RemoteViews rw = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.calendar_widget);



    packageManager=context.getPackageManager();

//code for other jobs

if (receiveIntent != null){
             manualUpdate = receiveIntent.getBooleanExtra("manual", false);

            final RemoteViews[] remoteViews= new RemoteViews[]{rw};
            if(manualUpdate){
                remoteViews[0].setViewVisibility(R.id.update_ready_text,View.VISIBLE);//work



                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        remoteViews[0].setViewVisibility(R.id.update_ready_text,View.INVISIBLE);//not work!!
                        System.out.println("handler ran is succes");
                    }
                });

            }
//code for other jobs...
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rw);
}
```

//out result:
I/System.out: onReceive : android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE

I/System.out: handler ran is succes.

///////the handler runs, but the 'textview' will not be invisible.which method would be appropriate?.thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(manualUpdate){
                remoteViews[0].setViewVisibility(R.id.update_ready_text,View.VISIBLE);//work



                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        remoteViews[0].setViewVisibility(R.id.update_ready_text,View.INVISIBLE);//
                        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds,rw);
                    }
                });

            }
```

*** i found the solution. i forgot update widget in handler. it works -:))))